# Regular expression accept custom numbers

Tags: regex

I need a help

How to change this regular expression that allows to accept positive numbers

like 0, 0.00, .02,etc.. ,

Now this accept 5 digits decimal that is greater than 0 and up to 100

```
"^100|(\d\d?)(\.(1[01]?|0\d?))?$"
```

Comment: You can ask for help here but never tell to do your job.

Comment: What does the regular expression do now, and what changes have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First you should wrap the whole expression except the string boundaries in a group. Otherwise your expression would just say *either start with … or end with …* as the `|` has a higher precedence than `^` and `$`:

```
^(100|(\d\d?)(\.(1[01]?|0\d?))?)$
```

And now a solution to your question:

```
^((100|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which language you are wishing to get the result but it seems quite simple.
The rules are input should start with either digit(s) or decimal point and then, either decimal point or digit(s).